# Baptized in a Mennonite church?

Tags: baptism, mennonite, membership

I grew up around the Amish, and Mennonite communities. However, my family was half Protestant half, well.. Not religious. I am a 21 year old dairy farmer, and not baptized. It was always left open to me to find what I believed, and follow that. I've always looked in to the Mennonite religion, with strong desire to learn more. However where I live now, there are no close-by Mennonite churches. I agree strongly with the way things are viewed in this religion and I'd like to follow the church as well as the lifestyle. I believe it's time. And its something I take seriously. My question is, would I be welcomed as a visitor in a Mennonite church? And if so, could I become a member if I truly decided that's what I want?

Comment: Why don't you just ask the closest Mennonite church to you?

Comment: @curiousdannii I don't understand the question. The OP says that they do not live close to any church (which makes one wonder how they would become an active member, but that is a separate issue).

Comment: Welcome to the site, Alyson. Would you say that you question is, basically, what is required to become a member of the Mennonite church?

Comment: @fredsbend There may not be one close to them, but there will always be a closest one!

Comment: I've been attending Mennonite churches most of my life, and I've never been to one that wouldn't welcome you, or anyone else. But the same can be said of most other denominations as well... and even so, there are likely exceptions. Your best bet is to go to a church (Mennonite or otherwise) and see if you feel welcome. If you don't, try another church.

Comment: Is this question really too broad if so why?